# WSPBuilder in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: 2007, visual-studio, wspbuilder

I have WSPBuilder 1.06 in Visual Studio 2008 (russian localization) for SharePoint 2007. I created a wsp project and added to it event handler. I tried to build this project using the command WSP Builder->Build WSP, but I got the error "value does not fall within the expected range". What do I do?

Comment: Please add more information to make users able to answer question, or the question will be closed.

Comment: i closed this due to lack of information. If you want it reopened, ask a new question with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough information to suggest a solution, but here are a few links --

http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/workitem/11301

http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/workitem/13169

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/294676f0-297e-4df3-b286-d468072e1d18/

Answer (score 1):

no too many clues but I would check WSPBuilder installation. The first step I would recommend is to try WSPBuilder command line to build your package. If it's ok that way you have to reinstall VS add-on.

Comment: I reinstalled wpsbuilder, but problem persists

Comment: but did you try command line package build?

Comment: no, i don't now how to do it)